# Is it possible to nest regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, nested

So i have this string:

```
http://www.whatever.com/whatever-c89-ca9840-cu3849
```

Is it possible to use a unique regular expression (preg_match) to:

1. Isolate `-ca9840`
2. Extract number `9840`

This is what i'm doing now:

preg_match('/-cu[\d]+-/', $uri, $mathes)

Comment: What have you tried? I can't figure out what you have in mind when you talk about nesting regular expressions.

Comment: preg_match('/-cu[\d]+-/', $uri, $mathes, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

Comment: @Rimbuaj,: Instead of putting it in a comment, edit your question and add the new info there.

Comment: Alan Moore done! (nice name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.whatever.com/whatever-c89-ca9840-cu3849';
if( preg_match('@-ca(\d+)@', $url, $matches) ){
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "-ca9840"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "9840"
}
```

Comment: can you explain this? i mean, is there a "concept" i must learn?

Comment: This is the most basic example of regular expression I can think of. So, to answer your question, I suggest you study the [PCRE Patterns](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) section of the manual or the regexp tutorial of your choice.

Comment: Ok, those @ sounded weird to me.

Comment: [Delimiters](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Using `/` tends to be annoying when you parse URLs ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No. It's that easy. A regular expression does not have memory apart from the state it's in.

Comment: sorry but i've read about backreference in regex an it actually says that in fact it has.